# How to get every element with the same class name remotely via jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, rss, each

I'm trying to get some data from [here](http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews) via an Ajax call. I can get the entire document in my console, but I do not know how to get individual elements. I'm wanting the title, and the content underneath.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); //This works
               //How to find titles and content underneath?

                $('itemcontent').each(function() { //This does not work
                    var itemcontent = $(this).text() + '<br>';
                    console.log(itemcontent);
                })
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

'itemcontent' is the text underneath the titles. What is the proper syntax to grab the text in these elements?

**Update**
I can now get data back, but only once. Am I not using .each() correctly or some other syntax? 
The weirdest part is that it's getting the **last** element, and not the first.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
       $(data).find('.itemcontent').each(function() { //I'm only getting one result back
           var text = $(this).text();
           $('#rss').html('<p>' + text + '</p>');

       })
  }
```

This is what I get back, the very last '.itemcontent' text on the page:

```
Sonos Inc, a maker of hi-tech wireless speakers, filed for an initial public offering on Friday, riding on the back of increasing popularity of streaming music through smartphone apps on connected audio systems.
```

Comment: you need to load the retrieved page into something and then parse it `$(data).find("itemcontent").each(...)`

Comment: or  `$(data).find(".itemcontent").each(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1**

You need to load the data returned into an element to process it like you are attempting `$(data).find(SELECTOR)`

**Problem 2**

[Each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) takes the array as the first parameter `$.each(array, function(index, element){});`

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $.each($(data).find('.itemcontent'),function() {
         var text = $(this).text();
         $('#rss').html('<p>' + text + '</p>');
      });
   }
});
```

**Problem 3**

You are just replacing the contents of `#rss` with each iteration of the array, this results in only the last result ending up in the element.  If you want them all you should be `appending` elements to `#rss`.  For example, `$("#rss").append($("<p>").html(text));`

Comment: I do note that there are two versions of `each` now that I look it up, the one I linked to and the one you were using.  Either works in your situation, it is primarily **problem 3** that is your latest issue.

Comment: It was .append() that fixed it! Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are looking for a tag and not a class. You need to have

```
$('.itemcontent').each(function() {
```

also you have to call the url as https and not http. It threw back an error for me

Comment: Edited my question to reflect my attempt at your answer.